# Adding two arrays into one

Tags: algorithm, sorting, merge, computer-science

I have two arrays (a and b) of size n, (positive whole numbers)
`a= [a1…..an] b= [b1….bn]`

I want to store them in array c, also an array of size n
 `c=[c1…..cn]`

where I add one element from a plus one element from b (each used once) into c, lets say the first element in c is combining a1+b3
Quick example:
`n=4 a=[a1,a2,a3,a4] b=[b1,b2,b3,b4]` 
one way could be:
 `c=[a1+b2,b3+a4,a2+b1,a3+b4]`
The problem is that I want to add them in a way so that the elements in c become as evenly distributed as possible,
One ideal case would be that c came out as:
`c=[5,5,5,5]`
but the numbers in a and b might not match up so they become even, so I want it to come as close to even as possible.

I an trying to find a way so that the difference between the biggest number in c minus the smallest number in c (after being combined as evenly as I can) to be as small as possible. In my optimal example above that would be 5-5=0 which is most optimal since 0 is the smallest minimum difference I want to achieve. Some other case with other numbers might come out as 6-5=1, which might be the smallest I could get in that situation

My way of going would be to sort array a in ascending order and my array b in descending order,and then combining them with the same element that they are in. Im not sure if this is the best way or the fastest to do this in, I want my code (doing it with python) to be fast. I cant come up with a better way where I could distribute them more evenly,any clue if there are better ways to solve this problem? I really appreciate all advice I could get! Thank you

When trying to solve it in a way where one of the arrays is ascending, and the other one being descending, there might already exist an algorithm that solves it better that I have not thought of. Thank you for reading!

Comment: (Didn't I see ["this"](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/157543/how-do-i-find-the-most-even-combination-for-two-arrays) question just the other day?)

Comment: I suggest trying to prove that your solution is optimal. It's an interesting exercise. Imagine that array a is sorted in ascending order. You sort b in descending order and pair the numbers accordingly. I sort b in some other order, and pair the numbers accordingly. Prove that my pairing is worse or equal to yours, but not better.

Comment: I think your approach is fine O(nlogn). I don't see how you can be any faster, except if you sort in O(n) by using radix sort or something. But I doubt it's faster in practice than your approach.

Comment: I am the creator of that post aswell, as you can see I have been trying for days to find a better way with no luck, so I wanted to ask here as well!

Comment: I was thinking of proving by contradiction, but what would that be? Sorting both of them in ascending order? I cant seem to find a solid proof and therefore am not trusting if this solution has a loophole

Comment: You probably need to specify more precisely what you want to minimize. max(c) - min(c) or the sum of the squared differences from the average or something else?

Comment: @maraca *"the difference between the biggest number in c minus the smallest number in c [...] to be as small as possible"*

Comment: @KellyBundy I saw that, but "after being combined as evenly as I can" is not clear. max(c) - min(c) seems to be the main concern, but it says nothing about the numbers in-between. Minimizing the sum of the squared differences from the average would specify it exactly.

Comment: (`creator of that post aswell` well, a somewhat sketchy proof by contradiction has just been posted as an answer over at CS. Proving optimality should - errm - *prove* difficult.)

Comment: @greybeard Hopefully you think that https://stackoverflow.com/a/75497214/585411 is a somewhat less sketchy proof.

Comment: (@btilly beautifully executed. Alas, I was thinking of proving time complexity ("asymptotically") optimal: the *problem* has no o(n log n) solution, none significantly faster than proportional to n log n.)

Comment: You removed all context from your question. It made no sense after the massive deletion, I've rolled it back.

Answer (score 3):

Your algorithm is both correct and fast.  It is just proving it that is optimal which is tricky.

We can do this by proving the following two results.

1. Any other matching of `a` and `b` will lead to a maximum at least as big as yours.
2. Any other matching of `a` and `b` will lead to a minimum at least as small as yours.

And the conclusion is that any other matching must have a maximum-minimum at least as big as yours.  From which yours must be optimal.

Now let's look at part 1.  Sort `a` ascending, and `b` descending.  Find the `i` such that `c[i] = a[i] + b[i]` is a maximum.  Suppose that `m` is any other matching where we're matching up `a[j] + b[m[j]]`.  Note that `m[1], ..., m[n]` is a permutation of `1, ..., n`.

If `a[i] + b[m[i]] >= a[i] + b[i]` then part 1 is true..

If `a[i] + b[m[i]] < a[i] + b[i]` then `b[m[i]] < b[i]` and so we must have `i < m[i]`.  Now there are `n-i` numbers in the range `i+1, ..., n`.  `m` maps something out of that range into that range.  Because `m` is a permutation, by the pigeonhole principle, `m` must map something in that range, out of that range.

In other words there must be a `j > i` such that `m[j] <= i`.  But now `a[i] <= a[j]` and `b[i] <= b[m[j]]` and therefore `a[i] + b[i] <= a[j] + b[m[j]]`.  And so part 1 is true again.

That concludes the proof of part 1.

The proof of part 2 is similar.  Except now `a[i] + b[i]` is at a minimum, `m[i] < i`, there is a `j < i` with `i <= m[j]`, `a[j] <= a[i]`, `b[m[j]] <= b[i]`, and `a[j] + b[m[j]] <= a[i] + b[i]`.

And as noted, part 1 and part 2 together implies that you've minimized the difference between the minimum and maximum.